# How to connect to an active directory server?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm using below code for connecting to an active directory server and retrieving its users.

But my web server is not in sub domain. Can I connect to it?

Or I should include its Ip address or something else?

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dps.com", "Raymond", "xxxxxxx");

DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))");

foreach (SearchResult result in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
   ResultPropertyCollection myResultPropColl = result.Properties;
   DataRow dr=reader.Tables[0].NewRow();
   dr[0]=myResultPropColl["samaccountname"][0].ToString()+"@"+Domain;
   reader.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
   Response.Write(myResultPropColl["samaccountname"][0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context - connects to the current default domain
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find user by name
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity("John Doe");

// find all users in your AD directory - set up a "query-by-example" 
// template to search for; here: a UserPrincipal, which is not locked out
UserPrincipal userTemplate = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
userTemplate.IsAccountLockedOut = false;

// create a PrincipalSearcher, based on that search template
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userTemplate);

// enumerate all users that this searcher finds
foreach(Principal foundPrincipal in searcher.FindAll())
{
   UserPrincipal foundUser = (foundPrincipal as UserPrincipal);

   // do something with the userTemplate
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

If you cannot upgrade to S.DS.AM, what you need to do is make sure to use a proper LDAP string to connect to your server. That string should be something like:

```
 LDAP://servername/OU=Users,DC=YourCompany,DC=com
```

The `servername` is optional - you can also leave that out. But the LDAP string needs to be made up of at least one `DC=xxxxx` string, and possibly other LDAP segments.